# Get grep result line by line and extract a single word from each line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am on Linux and I need to:

1. Find all `.cpp` files in all subdirectories of /source
2. Extract the name of file contained in all include statements one by one i.e from `#include "filename.h"` I have to extract `filename.h`
3. Lookup for each `filename.h` in all subrirectories and extract its path
4. Insert the path into comment in the end of corresponding include statement in every `.cpp`

For now I just managed to find all include statements with `grep` command however I need to read them rather line by line and also extract the `filename.h`from this line and input the location of the file in the end of the same line. Do I need sed or it will be better to save the result of `grep` in a variable and loop through it? Thank you.

Code snippet that allows me to print all include statements:

```
urdir=`pwd`
for f in `find $curdir/source/ -type f -a -name *.cpp`
do 
chmod +rwx $f
grep -E -s '^[#][include].*["|<].*["|>]$' $f 
done
```

Comment: Square brackets define bracket expressions, they only match one char defined in the set. Remove the brackets where you meant to match *sequences* of chars. E.g. `'^#include.*["<].*[">]$'`

Comment: Don't do chmod +rwx or (worse) chmod 777 - it is a newbie error. You only need to read the file, so +r will do. In fact, good practice is not to change anything as if someone has stopped it being readable, there might be a good reason for it.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ reports a number of warnings and errors. You should try to understand those, and perhaps prepare to ask a better-focused question.

Comment: Did you consider doing this in Python?  It would be way more robust, more readable, and better maintainable than a shell solution.

Comment: You can replace steps 1-2-3 by searching for all `*.h` files first. You might want to produce a `sed` command file with lines like `s=#include.*util.h[>"]=& /* /path/to/util.h */=`. Of course you test `sed -i -f commandfile $f` on a copy of your original files until you are happy.